# API returning an array inside of an object how to display contents- Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, api, django-views

So I am requesting spot price from cex API, it returns something like this
`{"data":[{"amount: "67000.0", "base": "BTC", "currency": "USD"}]}` of course there is more than one returned so I want to loop over it.

In my views.py I am passing it into my context `'price': price`. Then inside of my .html file I have a list with a for loop for example:

```
<ul>
  {% for x in price %}
    <li>{{ x }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Then when I open my .html page I get

data

But what I'd  like to be able to do is make a table where I have three columns to show the amount, base and currency. I am unsure on how to extract this data individualy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate over the `.values` of `price`, and then enumerate over the dictionaries in that list with:

```
<table>
{% for vs in price.values %}
    {% for v in vs %}
        <tr><td>{{ v.amount }}</td><td>{{ v.base }}</td><td>{{ v.currency }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Django templates, you can access to dictionary items with a expresión like `{{ dictionary.key }}`

```erlang
<ul>
  {% for x in price %}
    <li>{{ x.amount }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

See the docs on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups